# Flume Multiplexing not working

Tags: flume, multiplexing

I have configured my flume agent like below. Somehow, the flume agent doesn't run properly. It keeps hanging without any errors. Is there any problem with the below configuration.

FYI: I have a file named "country" with hard-coded header as state

```
#Define sources, sink and channels
foo.sources =  s1
foo.channels = chn-az  chn-oth
foo.sinks   =  sink-az sink-oth
#
### # # Define a source on agent and connect to channel memory-channel.
foo.sources.s1.type = exec
foo.sources.s1.command = cat /home/hadoop/flume/country.txt
foo.sources.s1.batchSize = 1
foo.sources.s1.channels = chn-ca  chn-oth

#selector configuration
foo.sources.s1.selector.type = multiplexing
foo.sources.s1.selector.header = state
foo.sources.s1.selector.mapping.AZ = chn-az
foo.sources.s1.selector.default    = chn-oth
#
#
### Define a memory channel on agent called memory-channel.
foo.channels.chn-az.type = memory
foo.channels.chn-oth.type = memory
#
#
##Define sinks that outputs to hdfs.
foo.sinks.sink-az.channel = chn-az
foo.sinks.sink-az.type = hdfs
foo.sinks.sink-az.hdfs.path = hdfs://master:9099/user/hadoop/flume
foo.sinks.sink-az.hdfs.filePrefix = statefilter
foo.sinks.sink-az.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
foo.sinks.sink-az.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
foo.sinks.sink-az.batchSize    = 1
foo.sinks.sink-az.rollInterval = 0
#
foo.sinks.sink-oth.channel = chn-oth
foo.sinks.sink-oth.type = hdfs
foo.sinks.sink-oth.hdfs.path = hdfs://master:9099/user/hadoop/flume
foo.sinks.sink-oth.hdfs.filePrefix = statefilter
foo.sinks.sink-oth.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
foo.sinks.sink-oth.batchSize    = 1
foo.sinks.sink-oth.rollInterval = 0
```

Thanks,
Vinoth

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the channels list configured at the source:

```
foo.sources.s1.channels = chn-ca  chn-oth
```

I think `chn-ca` should be `chn-az`.

Nevertheless, I think such a configuration will never work since the "state" header used by the selector is not created by any Flume component. You must introduce an interceptor for that, typically the [Regex Extractor Interceptor](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#regex-extractor-interceptor).